# django rest framework filter on foregin table

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

i'm writing API in django rest framework, i want to do a filter on a foreign key table.

want to do a filter in the scripts_details table as per the user. since scripts_details is not having user, i am trying to filter in the script tables. but it is not happening.

i tired   `return ScriptDetails.objects.filter(script=scriptid, script.user=self.request.user)`

Models.py

```
class Scripts(models.Model):
    tutorial = models.OneToOneField(TutorialDetail)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    data_file = models.FileField(upload_to='scripts',blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='user_id')


class ScriptDetails(models.Model):
    cue=models.TextField()
    narration=models.TextField()
    order=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    script=models.ForeignKey('Scripts', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

serializer.py

```
class ScriptsDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model=ScriptDetails
    fields=('cue','narration','order','script')
```

views.py

```
class ScriptsDetailsList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class=ScriptsDetailSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
      scriptid = self.kwargs.get('scriptid')
      return ScriptDetails.objects.filter(script=scriptid)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^api/scriptsdetails/(?P<scriptid>[0-9]+)/', views.ScriptsDetailsList.as_view())
```

Comment: what are exceptions you are facing?

Comment: only issue is i can't do a filter in a parent table (script) from child table(script details). is it possible in django rest fraework